# NotFoundError - The EB CLI cannot find your SSH key file for keyname

Tags: amazon-ec2, elastic-beanstalk

I ran the command

```
eb use my-environment-name
```

Inside of my directory:

```
/myProject
```

I have a directory `.ssh` with the keypair file `'mykey'`

```
/myProject/.ssh/mykey
```

I then run `eb ssh`

I then get this error:

```
INFO: Attempting to open port 22.
INFO: SSH port 22 open.
ERROR: NotFoundError - The EB CLI cannot find your SSH key file for keyname "codesto". Your SSH key file must be located in the .ssh folder in your home directory.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be misreading the error, which finishes like "`in the .ssh folder in your home directory`".
You should copy your key to the appropriate directory in your `home`

```
cp /myProject/.ssh/mykey ~/.ssh/
```

You might have another error on the way (key name or permissions), but at least the `home` problem should be handled.